# How to combine multiple csv files into a single excel sheet using unix shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, unix, xls

E.g. we have 3 `csv` files `1.csv`, `2.csv`,`3.csv`.
I want the output as `All.xls`

containing

the 3 `csv` files `1.csv`, `2.csv` and `3.csv` in their respective tab.

Comment: Do the files have headers, it would be mucheasier to merge 3 csv files into one big csv file, and import that into excel rather than generate an xls from a shell.

Comment: Just check my answer and let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2):

Yes the are multiple ways to do what you want. Perl, Python and Ruby have the appropriate modules. Probably other scripting languages also. Depends on which scripting language you are comfortable with.

Here is a pointer to one way of doing what you want using Python: [Python script to convert CSV files to Excel](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2007/02/python-script-to-convert-csv-files-to.html)

Comment: I do not want to convert csv to xls, if you completely understood my requirement then kindly comment, I want the script in unix

Comment: Hope this will help you [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293775/merging-contents-of-multiple-csv-files-into-single-csv-file)

Comment: @VaibhavGehlot: As you have said it is quite direct in python, or other scripting languages!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this well maintained Perl script:

https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV_XS

which exists in most Linux distributions (although with different names):

https://repology.org/project/perl:text-csv-xs/versions

Here is the syntax

`csv2xlsx -o ~/All.xlsx 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

1-open an empty excel file then go to `file` then `options` then choose `customize Ribbon` then select `developer` then press `ok`

2-Now you have `developer` tap showing in your ribbon so all that you need to do is to select it then press on `VisualBasic` icon

3-Microsoft Visual basic for applications window will pop, select `insert` then `modules`

4-paste the following code into the empty window:

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

5-press f5 to run, navigate to your CSV files then press `ok` and wait for the VBA script to do its magic = this will transform CSV files to xlsx

6-Now delete the previous VBA script in `modules` and add the following script

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

7-press f5 to run, navigate to your files then press `ok` and wait for the VBA script to do its magic = this will transform xlsx files to one excel file

Answer (score 0):

The command to cat files together to produce a new file is `cat`. However, if you simply did a

```
 cat *csv >All.xls
```

you would also have header lines in the middle of the resulting files. There are two ways to work around this problem:

The first involves that you create temporary files out of each csv file, where the header line is missing, before putting together the pieces. This can be done using the `tail` command, for example

```
tail -n +2 2.csv >2_without_header.csv
```

The second possibility may or may not be applicable in your case. If - as it is often the case with CSV files - the order of the lines doesn't matter and duplicate lines can be ignored and - as it is likely in your case - the headers are identical, you could simply do a

```
sort -u *csv >All.xls
```

Comment: In my understanding he doesn't want to concatanete the 3 csv files but want to make an xls file with 3 sheets that will contain the data of the csv file!

Comment: I first also thought this, because he named the new file with .xls, but look at his comment above, where he says explicitly: *I do not want to convert csv to xls*! I think it's just poor naming. Actually, since Excel works just fine with CSV files, it indeed does make sense to stick with CSV.

Comment: I want 3 tabs in a single excel, first tab contains data for 1.csv, 2nd tab contains data for 2.csv and so on.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, my solution for sure is not appropriate ...... In this case, you want to convert the CSV files into Excel Format. Well, this has been answered in a good way by VaibhavGehlot already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `awk '!a[$0]++' ./*.csv > ./all.xls` 
This command will combine all the csv files in current folder and create a new file: `all.xls` with single header row.

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the original need: all the CSV files are not put in multiple sheets, and all files needs to have the same structure. On top of it, the resulting file is not in Excel format, it's just a CSV with an `.xls` extension that will just barely might open into Excel with most probably some encoding issue if the original file are in UTF-8 for instance.